# Recommended method for updating/adding menus when adding new theme

Tags: theme-development, menus, import, production

I'm working locally on a completely new theme. Once I'm done I'm going to use the "test drive" plugin to allow admins to test the theme before switching over to it. The problem is that with the new theme there are more menus & updates to the existing ones. How do I manage adding/updating the menus without messing with the live site?

Can I somehow import them?
Or while I'm test driving the new theme, can I add the menus or will they be added globally?

In the meantime, what I've started to implement is:
1. Check if the menu exists. If it does then build it the normal WP way.
2. As a fallback, revert to a hardcoded menu.

So I'd upload the theme, activate it, add the menus and after launch I'd then have to go and remove the fallbacks.

Not sure if this is right. Seems a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

They are included in the WordPress export file and there's also a plugin which only exports the menus in WordPress.http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/

Hasn't been updated in 2 years however it did test it last year and works.

Comment: Quick reply, thanks. Hmm, the lack of activity scares me on that. For the first option, how would I go about that? I'd have to export from the live site, import locally, add the menus and import to the live site overwriting everything (incl. anything added after my previous export)? That doesn't sound great either :/.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is because any menu's you create will be saved by WordPress and you can preview them when changing themes.

Comment: Maybe I'm just looking at this the wrong way. Don't know why I haven't thought of this (probably because I'm new to WP) but would an obvious solution be to add new unshown menus, switch the theme and then assign the new menus to the correct theme locations? How would this fit in with test driving the theme? Is it possible to test drive the theme and put the new  menus in the theme's locations without harming the live site?

Comment: What most theme developers do is include an export file in the theme so people can import the demo content if they want.